# Regex code in javascript for restricting input field

Tags: javascript, regex, input

I have a question about restricting the value entered in some input field. I would like to input this :

9digits-whatever, for example 101010101-Teststring.

I have come up with this regex as a solution, but it does not seem to be correct:

```
^\d{9}\-[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$
```

Any ideas on this one?

Thank you.

Comment: Just use `/^\d{9}-.+$/`

Comment: Remember that `/[a-zA-Z0-9_]/` is exactly `/\w/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below  regex would match 9 digits follwed by `-` and any number of characters.,

```
^\d{9}-.*$
```

If you want a minimum of one character followed by `-`, then try the below regex.

```
^\d{9}-.+$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the beginning of the line.
- `\d{9}` Exactly 9 digits.
- `\-` Literal `-` symbol.
- `.*` Matches any character zero or more times.
- `$` End of the line.

Comment: Thank you, Avinash Raj, that did it!

Comment: IS there any need to escape hyphen?

Comment: @Braj but both will work. And op wants to match any character after `-`.

Comment: That's correct but there is no need to escape hyphen. Is it?

Comment: Do you know why $ doesn't work as negative `[^$]*` look up but works if added in the end.

Answer (score 1):

- There is no need to escape hyphen `-`.
- Use `\w` that include `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Try below regex if there is only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` after 9 digits and hyphen.

```
^\d{9}-\w*$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/rT1bR0/3)

Comment: OP's `$` in this case matches the end of the string, not a literal `'$'`

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight sorry that part is deleted but $ works in the end but not as part of negative character set.