# Why does this regex work with and without hyphens / dashes escaped

Tags: javascript, regex, perl

given the following string:

```
blablabla
X-FOO-BAR:blaaaa
blafoobla
```

both of these regexes remove the second line

1. `s/X-FOO-BAR.*?$//gismo`
2. `s/X\-FOO\-BAR.*?$//gismo`

I'm not completely understanding why the regex without the hyphens works in this case.  Can someone clear this up for me?  I've tested it in both perl and javascript regex engine.

Cheers!

Comment: Question comes from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700477/regex-code-in-javascript-for-restricting-input-field) :)

Comment: Hyphens should only need escaped when in the middle of a character class (`[ ]`). Technically, they don't even need escaped when at the beginning or end of a character class, but it's good to be consistent and always escape them when in a character class

Comment: Read the [EXPLANATION](http://regex101.com/#javascript) section about `\-`

Comment: @Ian escaping hypen in the middile of char class may work or maynot.

Comment: @Braj ah, I see.  Thanks for the link.  I don't think that question's title makes it easy to locate though in this particuliar case.  None the less thanks.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Why do you think that it "may not"?

Comment: @Ian see here http://regex101.com/r/wY8kG1/21. It's better to avoid placing it at the middle.

Comment: @AvinashRaj That regex makes no sense. You're misusing `-`. You're starting a range (by having `a-`), but not ending the range (by having a `\-` before the `z`). The problem has nothing to do with escaping `-` in the middle of a character class, but misusing `-` for a range

Comment: Some may think like that. It's also a middle.

Comment: @Ian did you note that, it will work http://regex101.com/r/wY8kG1/22

Comment: @AvinashRaj Interesting! I didn't realize that. Hmm that's weird

Comment: @Ian: That is nonsense. There are no ranges. A hyphen will define a range if it appears between two other characters inside a character class, but in general it has no special meaning

Comment: @Borodin I have no idea what you're referring to. You've just said exactly what I mentioned earlier (they need to be escaped only in the middle of a character class, otherwise they're normal), so what's your point?

Comment: @Ian: *"I have no idea what you're referring to"* I wouldn't be so proud of it if I was you

Comment: @Borodin There are several comments (of mine) here about hyphens and escaping. You're wasting time by being non-specific, non-helpful and over-critical of something that's already been resolved by me and AvinashRaj.

Comment: @Ian: It is you that is maintaining this dialogue, not me. You are clearly far more fond of yourself than of accuracy so I have no interest in correcting you

Comment: @Borodin I'm not complaining about maintaining the dialogue. I want to understand your original unclear point. There's no concept of fondness, just confusion. Since you don't want to correct me, you'd rather bloat these comments with pointless content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape hyphen when it is outside the character class. In the character class, you must place the hypen at the start or at the last. But if you place it in the middle, escaping may work or maynot.

Comment: ah, thanks for clearing that up.  Now I can explain why something I wrote isn't a bug, lol.

Comment: bug? it isn't a bug. `-` in char class has a special meaning. It means range.for ex, [a-z] matches any lowercase alphabet.

Comment: @AvinashRaj The OP is saying that with your explanation, he can now confirm his regex **isn't** a bug, and is expected behavior

Comment: @Ian correct.  I got called out on using the one without escaped dash as a bug, but I had tested it successfully.  Just needed an explanation as to why it worked.